# transform Post request using the Post-Redirect-Get pattern in java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to transform a post request using the post/redirect/get pattern in order to prevent an "ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path" error. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910526/spring-ambiguous-handler-methods-mapped-for-http-path?noredirect=1#comment61426513_36910526) for details.

Here is the initial code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {
    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE = "topologie";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
    public String genererCle(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
    }
```

I don't really understand how to re code it using the PRG pattern. Even if I think that I understand the underlying concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add another method that can handle a GET request for the same url mapping.
So in your POST method you just make a redirection and in your GET method you can do all the business process.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bus/topologie")
public class TopologieController {
    private static final String VIEW_TOPOLOGIE = "topologie";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "genererCle" })
    public String genererClePost(final Topologie topologie, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("genererCle") final String genererCle, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("genererCle", genererCle);
        return "redirect:/bus/topologie";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "genererCle" })
    public String genererCleGet(final Topologie topologie, final Model model)
        throws IOException {
        cadreService.genererCle(topologie);
        return VIEW_TOPOLOGIE;
    }
```

Comment: That's nearly what I've done before, but I've an error : "Duplicate method genererCle(Topologie, Model) in type TopologieController".

Comment: @jayjaypg22: Yeah you are right. I have edited my answer and change the method name by adding a suffix to each method that match the supported request method. This way it should work.

Comment: While debugging, using this code it comes into the POST request and redirect to the form but it doesn't enter in the GET method.

Comment: @jayjaypg22: I see the point. It is because the method which is mapped to the GET request expect to find in the request a parameter named "genererCle" and it is not present. I have updated my answer to solve that problem.

Comment: There is still an error : Error code 400, The URL is http://localhost:8081/bus/topologie?genererCle=true%2C , I tried removing the %2C character : It works a bit better : The form is displayed but still empty. It enters in the genererCleGet yet.

Comment: Why there is a "," (%2C is the hex code for ",") and the end of your URL? Then for the form you should use the model attribute to set what is need by your form. As it is solving your initial problem could you approve my solution?

Comment: I don't know why it add the comma, I add genererCle = "true"; and the redirection works. But the global solution (not yours, the PRG pattern) doesn't work at all : At the end, the form is displayed like if nothing happened.

Comment: @jayjaypg22: Can you edit your question or create a new one and post a bit more regarding your form cause it is really difficult to give you some help without seing the code.